# insert a where condition in an aggregated sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to put a "where" clause in my aggregated sql statement,

what I want is to get the sum of qty and only display those who have a 30 or less (including zero) quantities sold.
I tried putting it in the "on" part but to no avail

```
SELECT p.id, p.names,p.image, coalesce(sum(o.qty), 0) as sum_product_qty 
from products p left join orders_item o on p.id = o.product_id                        
and date(o.datesales) <= curdate() and date(o.datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day  and
sum_product_qty <= 30 group by p.id, p.names order by sum_product_qty desc
```

this is my sql statement

```
SELECT p.id, p.names,p.image, coalesce(sum(o.qty), 0) as sum_product_qty 
from products p left join orders_item o on p.id = o.product_id 
and date(o.datesales) <= curdate() and date(o.datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
group by p.id, p.names order by sum_product_qty desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Having` to filter your aggregated groups.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.names,
       p.image,
       COALESCE(SUM(o.qty), 0) AS sum_product_qty
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders_item o 
     ON p.id = o.product_id
     AND date(o.datesales) <= curdate()
     AND date(o.datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 DAY
GROUP BY p.id,
         p.names,
         p.image
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(o.qty), 0) <= 30
ORDER BY COALESCE(SUM(o.qty), 0) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `having` clause instead.

```
SELECT p.id, p.names,p.image, coalesce(sum(o.qty), 0) as sum_product_qty 
from products p left join orders_item o on p.id = o.product_id 
and date(o.datesales) <= curdate() and date(o.datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
group by p.id, p.names order by sum_product_qty desc HAVING sum_product_qty <= 30;
```

A `HAVING` clause in SQL specifies that an SQL SELECT statement should only return rows where aggregate values meet the specified conditions. It was added to the SQL language because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

The aggregated SQL statement groups the data, but the `WHERE` clause operates on the data row-wise, hence throwing an error.
The `HAVING` clause filters the data on the group row but not on the individual row.

Comment: it returned an error >right syntax to use near 'HAVING sum_product_qty <= 30 LIMIT 0

Comment: Try using this, the HAVING clause must be after GROUP BY

```SQL
SELECT p.id, p.names,p.image, coalesce(sum(o.qty), 0) as sum_product_qty 
from products p left join orders_item o on p.id = o.product_id 
and date(o.datesales) <= curdate() and date(o.datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
group by p.id, p.names HAVING sum_product_qty <= 30 order by sum_product_qty desc;
```